# react-dom 17.0.0 update error TypeError: init is not a function

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-dom

Updating react-dom from 16.3 to 17.0.0 in my CRA, getting the following error once I upgrade react-dom. Have had no previous issues updating react-dom until now.

Anyone know what could be causing the error or have possibly encountered an error like this previously?

I will check the react-dom repo in the meantime.

Comment: i am upgrade . with commands `yarn upgrade react@latest react-dom@latest` and last command `yarn`.and not problem.

Comment: thanks will try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks A.R.SEIF, that fixed it, had not updated my version of react from 16.3 to 17.
Should have updated react first instead of react-dom.
Thanks for your help, much appreciated!